# Connector/Net 6.3.6 install rollsback without message

Tags: installation, mysql, connector

I' using a VM with Windows XP.
I just tried to install mysql.data.msi from [Windows (x86, 32-bit), ZIP Archive](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/)

After copying new files, I see Rollback action.

Where can I find an error log or which .NET Version must be installed?

Answer (score 0):

After installing [Microsoft WebMatrix](http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/), I had no problems installing Connector/Net 6.3.6.